# Second differences sequences ratios

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For two sequences x and y, taking second differences ddx and ddy,
if ddx/ddy gives a constant sequence, are there any general properties of x and y that can be described related to this?  Ie maybe similar to a sequence z where the second difference sequence has constant values, z is a quadratic sequence?

Also is there a way to combine x and y into a new sequence k=f(x,y) so that the second differences of k gives a constant second differences sequence?

Example for x and y:

x= 1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29

y= 11,2,1,8,7,14,13,4

First differences:

dx= 6,4,2,4,2,4,6

dy= -9,-1,7,-1,7,-1,-9

Second differences:

ddx= -2,-2,2,-2,2,2

ddy= 8,8,-8,8,-8,-8

ddy/ddx= -4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4

Edit1:

Examples of sequences that have the same second differences sequence ddx={-2, -2, 2, -2, 2, 2}:

x1 = {1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 8};

x2 = {2, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 9};

x3 = {3, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 10};

x4 = {3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3};

x5 = {4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4};

x6 = {5, 7, 7, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5};

x7 = {6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 4, 4, 6};

x8 = {7, 9, 9, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7};

x9 = {8, 10, 10, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8};

x10 = {9, 10, 9, 6, 5, 2, 1, 2};

x1,x2,x3 all have the same first differences sequence:
{3,1,-1,1,-1,1,3}

x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9 all have the same first differences sequence:
{2,0,-2,0,-2,0,2}

x10 first differences sequence:
{1,-1,-3,-1,-3,-1,1}

Edit2: added Mathematica code with formula C=-1/A076512 based on comment

````
(*test of finding C from A076512 for x=A038566 and y=A308121 *)
nToUse = 14

A076512 = 
  Table[Denominator[(n - EulerPhi[n])/EulerPhi[n]], {n, nToUse}];

A308121 = 
  Table[With[{a = n/GCD[n, #], b = Numerator[#/n]}, 
      MapIndexed[a First@#2 - b #1 &, 
       Flatten@Position[GCD[Table[Mod[k, n], {k, n - 1}], n], 
          1] /. {} -> {1}]] &@EulerPhi@n, {n, nToUse}];

A038566 = 
  Table[Flatten[
    Position[GCD[Table[Mod[j, w], {j, 1, w - 1}], w], 1]], {w, 1, 
    nToUse}];

y = A308121[[nToUse]]

x = A038566[[nToUse]]

C1 = -1/A076512[[nToUse]]
(*C2=ConstantArray[Cc,Length[x]-2]*)

dx = Differences[x]
ddx = Differences[dx]

dy = Differences[y]
ddy = Differences[dy]

ddx == C1*ddy

w = x - C1*y
dw = Differences[w]
ddw = Differences[dw]

x - C1*y 


Out[704]= 14

Out[708]= {4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3}

Out[709]= {1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13}

Out[710]= -(1/3)

Out[711]= {2, 2, 4, 2, 2}

Out[712]= {0, 2, -2, 0}

Out[713]= {1, 1, -5, 1, 1}

Out[714]= {0, -6, 6, 0}

Out[715]= True

Out[716]= {7/3, 14/3, 7, 28/3, 35/3, 14}

Out[717]= {7/3, 7/3, 7/3, 7/3, 7/3}

Out[718]= {0, 0, 0, 0}

Out[719]= {7/3, 14/3, 7, 28/3, 35/3, 14}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $ddx/ddy = C$ in your notation. Then $ddx = C\ ddy$, and so the sequence $w = x - Cy$ satisfies $ddw = 0$. Consequently, $w$ is a linear sequence (an arithmetic progression). And conversely, if $x - Cy$ is a linear sequence then $ddx/ddy = C$.